# Ambiguity around mapping between GeoJSON FeatureCollection and Leaflet's Layers and LayerGroups

Tags: leaflet

The Leaflet documentation says that its GeoJSON object inherits from its FeatureGroup object which inherits from its LayerGroup object which inherits from its Layer object. It also says that the GeoJSON object can take as input a GeoJSON Feature or FeatureCollection. If I create a Leaflet GeoJSON object with a GeoJSON FeatureCollection, is each GeoJSON Feature in the FeatureCollection a Leaflet LayerGroup or is each GeoJSON feature a Layer in the LayerGroup? So then if I only had a GeoJSON Feature and not a FeatureCollection, is that just a Layer and not a LayerGroup? I'm a bit confused on the mapping between the two models.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```js
L.geoJSON(whatever)
```

...you get a Leaflet "GeoJSON" **Layer Group**, which indeed inherits from Leaflet Feature Group.

Then what is contained in that group indeed depends on what is "whatever":

- a single GeoJSON **Feature** with simple geometry (e.g. no multipoint) => a single Leaflet **Layer**
- an array of such simple Features, or a Feature Collection of such simple Features => as many Leaflet **Layers** (non group)
- for each item which is not a simple Feature (e.g. a nested Feature Collection, a Feature with Geometry Collection, or a complex geometry like multipoint), you will get a **nested** Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group, which contains the corresponding child Layers (or nested groups again if necessary)

Comment: I did some experimentation where I used three different 'whatever's. I used a FeatureCollection with 3 features of geometry LineString; I used a FeatureCollection with 1 feature of geometry Point; and one Feature with geometry Point. All three L.geoJSON objects had a property of _layers, and the number of items in that _layers property corresponded to the number of Features, regardless of whether I used a FeatureCollection or a Feature. Within each individual item, there was a single 'feature' property. So for your first bullet, I think I got a an array of Leaflet Layers (non group) of size 1.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, sorry if it was not clear enough.